# How do I access data from a js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Test.vue

```
<template>
      <div>
        <button @click="test()">test</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import logs from './data.js'
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
            logitems1: logs.data.infomation,
            logitems2:
          {
            log1d: 1,
            logDetail: "This is some log detail for log 1",
            logType: "general",
            createdBy: "name",
            CreatedAt: "date",
          },
        }
        },
        methods:{
          test(){
             console.log(this.logitems1.log1d)
             console.log(this.logitems2.log1d)
          }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

data.js

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      infomation: {
        log1d: 1,
        logDetail: "This is some log detail for log 1",
        logType: "general",
        createdBy: "name",
        CreatedAt: "date",
      },
    };
  },
};
```

Access to logitems2 is possible but I can't access the data in logitems1, which has all the same information. I'm trying to access data from files other than components, which I can't figure out how to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a functional call.

```
<script>
    import logs from './data.js'
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
            logitems1: logs.data().infomation,
            logitems2:
          {
            log1d: 1,
            logDetail: "This is some log detail for log 1",
            logType: "general",
            createdBy: "name",
            CreatedAt: "date",
          },
        }
        },
        methods:{
          test(){
             console.log(this.logitems1.log1d)
             console.log(this.logitems2.log1d)
          }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

But if you just only want the data to be available exporting the object from js file without function would be better approach.

logdata.js

```
export default logInformation{
    log1d: 1,
    logDetail: "This is some log detail for log 1",
    logType: "general",
    createdBy: "name",
    CreatedAt: "date",
}
```

and then directly use as

```
import logInformation from "logdata.js"

console.log(logInformation)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer
I had to run it like this because data.js was not created by me. Just a caller

Comment: Sure. Since you are using Vue, you can also try to get the initial data in the created hook.

Comment: Let me ask you some more. How can I change data in js file from test.vue?

Comment: add a function in the js file(return the updated data object) and call that from .vue file

Comment: @MetalzoneRockneverdie if you want to maintain the state try using Vuex or Pinia. That'll be better option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to add function data update function in data.js.
still can't figure it out

Comment: You have to make a global dataobject in the js file. 
let dataObject = { a: 1, b: 2 };
module.exports = {
  getData: function () {
    return dataObject;
  },
  updataData: function () {
    dataObject.c = 3;
    return dataObject;
  },
};
Then import and use